# Laravel relationship : relationship that does not return me what I ask

Tags: relationship, laravel-7

rI am new to laravel 7 and I still have a few small difficulties.

I have two tables: users and services. These two tables have a relation to retrieve a user's service.

```
$users= User::with('poseur')->get();
```

It returns all users even those who do not meet the conditions of my relationship.

I use scope in service model:

```
public function scopePoseurs(){
    return $query->whereRaw('slug','pos')
}
```

And i use belongsTo relation in user model :

```
public function poseur(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Service')->poseurs();
}
```

Exemple: we hase 2 users:
first: Daniel have service slug = 'pos',
second: Patrick have service slug ='dev'

When i use `$users=User::with('poseur')->get();`, i see Daniel and Patrick.
While there should be only Daniel.

Can you help me understand ?

Thanks !

Comment: `User::with('poseur')->get();` this will return all the user from `users` table. If the user has relation with poseur, then it will return data feom `poseur`,  otherwise not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with()` is for eager loading. That basically means, along the main model, Laravel will preload the relationship(s) you specify. This is especially helpful if you have a collection of models.

If you want to return all user, that has relation with `poseur` only, then use `has()` method :

```
$users= User::has('poseur')->get();
```

Ther is also a method called `whereHas()`, which allows you to specify additional filters for the related model to check :

```
$users = User::whereHas('poseur', function($q){
    $q->where('created_at', '>=', '2020-01-01 00:00:00');
})->get();
```

Comment: Hi sta, thanks for you help. Has and wereHas return empty array :/

Comment: I think you need to change `return $this->belongsTo('App\Service')->poseurs():` to `return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');`

Comment: Indeed it seems more logical. Now it works fine. Thank you !